# How to set context to fix AWS CDK setContext error when updating past v1.9.0?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript, aws-cdk-context

I’m trying to update some AWS CDK code past version 1.9.0 to version 1.152.0.
However, there’s one issue that is causing a problem - the setContext code is not valid anymore.

The error message I'm seeing is ‘Cannot set context after children have been added: Tree’

The code I am trying to update is:

```
const app = new cdk.App();

let stage: string = app.node.tryGetContext('stage');

// AppConfig is a custom defined interface  
// stageConfig is a variable of custom defined interface, StageConfig
const appConfig: AppConfig = {
  domainName: app.node.tryGetContext('domainName'),
  isProduction: stage === 'prod',
  stageName: stage,
  // default to getting dev config if stage is other than prod or test
  stageConfig: app.node.tryGetContext(stage === 'prod' || stage === 'test' ? stage : 'dev')
};

// set appConfig as a context variable for downstream stacks to use
app.node.setContext('config', appConfig);
```

I believe the main issue is that when the variable `app` is being defined, it now needs to include the set context data. That means I cannot use `app.node.tryGetContext` anymore because it's referencing the variable I am trying to define.

I tried to set `stage` to `process.env.STAGE` and `domainName` to `process.env.DOMAINNAME` but both seem to always return 'undefined':

```
let stage = process.env.STAGE || 'dev';

let app = new cdk.App({
  context: { ['config']: {
    domainName: process.env.DOMAINNAME,
    isProduction: stage === 'prod',
    stageName: stage,
    stageConfig: process.env.STAGE === (stage === 'prod' || stage === 'test' ? stage : 'dev')
  }}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting context on the `App` level is not possible after `1.9.0` per https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/4359

Your options are to either set it at a construct level (instead of app) or initialize the app with the context like you're doing in your second example, but then you cannot refer to any existing context variables.

`process.env` contains your environment variables. If it returns `undefined`, that means that there's no env variable with that name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So you're saying `setContext` can still be used in the stack.ts file (where I have the code `export class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {...}`)? The code above is in a separate file (app.ts), where `app` is initialized and `new MyStack` is created. Is there any advantage to either option - either initializing the app with the context in app.ts (with a .env file I assume since the variables I'm trying to access are returning not defined) or using `setContext` in stack.ts?

Comment: It depends on where you want your context to be available. If you only have a single stack, then I would use the `setContext` method on the stack, since that allows you to refer to existing context values. But other stacks will not see this change in the context.

Comment: I have 3 stacks, 3 stages - dev, test, prod. I've tried setting the context a couple different ways based on what you suggested, both in my app.ts file and:/ in my stack.ts file just to see, but for each attempt I'm receiving an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'policyFragment')" at `const fragment = principal.policyFragment;` I'm not sure if that's related to setting the context or maybe a different issue altogether..

Comment: Different issue.